# Get value of element in Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my foreach loop to get at the values from a multi-dimensional array

```
$_coloredvariables = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_coloredvariables', true );
foreach ($_coloredvariables as $key => $value) {
   var_dump($value);
}
```

Which outputs this:

```
array
  'label' => string 'Color' (length=5)
  'size' => string 'small' (length=5)
  'displaytype' => string 'square' (length=6)
  'values' => 
    array
      'dark-night-angel' => 
        array
          'type' => string 'Image' (length=5)
          'color' => string '#2c4065' (length=7)
          'image' => string '' (length=0)
      'forest-green' => 
        array
          'type' => string 'Color' (length=5)
          'color' => string '#285d5f' (length=7)
          'image' => string '' (length=0)
      'voilet' => 
        array
          'type' => string 'Color' (length=5)
          'color' => string '#6539c9' (length=7)
          'image' => string '' (length=0)
      'canary-yellow' => 
        array
          'type' => string 'Color' (length=5)
          'color' => string 'grey' (length=4)
          'image' => string '' (length=0)
```

And then to only get the values array I can do this:

```
foreach ($_coloredvariables as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($value['values']);
}
```

which outputs this:

```
array
  'dark-night-angel' => 
    array
      'type' => string 'Image' (length=5)
      'color' => string '#2c4065' (length=7)
      'image' => string '' (length=0)
  'forest-green' => 
    array
      'type' => string 'Color' (length=5)
      'color' => string '#285d5f' (length=7)
      'image' => string '' (length=0)
  'voilet' => 
    array
      'type' => string 'Color' (length=5)
      'color' => string '#6539c9' (length=7)
      'image' => string '' (length=0)
  'canary-yellow' => 
    array
      'type' => string 'Color' (length=5)
      'color' => string 'grey' (length=4)
      'image' => string '' (length=0)
```

What I can't figure out is how to get these elements in the array structure

**"dark-night-angel",
"forest-green",
"voilet",
"canary-yellow"**

Without using specific names:

```
var_dump($value['values']['dark-night-angel'])
```

Something that is more dynamic, of course this doesn't work:

```
var_dump($value['values'][0][0]);
```

thanks

Comment: `$_coloredvariables` has only 1 element? Always?

Comment: `$_coloredvariables  = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_coloredvariables', true );` I don't think so should be only one entry for returned post meta data.

Comment: You do a foreach of var_dumps and I only see 1 dumped var in the output, so I assumed there was only 1... Can you show a `var_export($_coloredvariables)` instead, so we'll know what it looks like complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a foreach-loop in your foreach-loop.

```
foreach($_coloredvariables as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value['values'] as $valkey => $values) {
        var_dump($valkey, $values);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had tried that as well sorry forgot to mention but it only gets me the contents of the array: `array 'type' => string 'Color' (length=5)
'color' => string 'grey' (length=4)'image' => string '' (length=0)` not the name of that array grouping `'canary-yellow' =>`

Comment: Replace `$values)` with `$valkey => $values)` and you can use $valkey to get the key.

Answer (score 0):

For 1 `$value` (so probably inside that foreach):

```
$colors = array_keys($value['values']);
```

If you want all the colors in all the values in `$_coloredvariables`, you'll need that foreach:

```
$colors = array();
foreach ($_coloredvariables as $key => $value) {
  $colors = array_merge($colors, array_keys($value['values']));
}
```

This ONLY returns the color keys. NOT the contents of those elements (`type`, `color` & `image`).

Is that what you need..?

Comment: This is an excellent answer why the heck did someone down vote you?

Comment: Who knows!? People, what a bunch of bastards!